# jQuery descendants selector with multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select all text areas, inputs and selects which are descendants of an element with a specific class. I tried this:

```
$('.parent textarea,input,select')
```

But it gives strange results. It selects elements even if there are no elements with `parent` class. An example: http://jsfiddle.net/v3cmjedk/

What's wrong with this selector and how should my selector look like?

I am using jQuery version 1.12.0.

Comment: `$('.parent').find('textarea,input,select')`. In CSS (and in jQuery) selectors are separated by `,`. Note: Your jQuery version is extremely old.

Comment: You can try also `$('.parent textarea,.parent input,.parent select')` since `,` is working as `or` in this case so `input` and `select` in the question will be treated as any element of that type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'.parent textarea,input,select'` string contains three unrelated selectors divided by `,`. You need to add the `.parent` to the `input` and `select` as well:

`'.parent textarea, .parent input, .parent select'`

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that your selector essentially says "select every textarea that is inside a container with the .parent class and also EVERY input and EVERY select element, no matter where they are".

So you just have to write `$('.parent textarea, .parent input, .parent select')`.

A different (but afaik less performant) way would be `$('.parent').find('textarea, input, select')`

Comment: That's  a valid CSS selector. It just doesn't do what OP expects it to do!